# Ethereum wallet on two devices?

Tags: wallets, accounts, mac-osx

I have a few problems, and I am not sure how to solve them.  I transferred ethereum from Coinbase to a wallet that I originally created on a Mac.  The initial sync was not yet complete, and it is taking days and days (and slowing down my other work).  I haven't yet "received" the ether into the Mac wallet.  Can I sync the blockchain on another device and receive the ether there?  I am a novice here.  Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can most definitely have the same Ethereum account on more than one device, all you have to do is import the private key.

Which wallet are you using? I'll assume it's mist, although I believe this method will work for a few different wallets. On your mac navigate to the folder `~/Library/Ethereum/keystore` (You might have to copy and paste this path in Finder `Folder --» Go to Folder` in the top bar menu) now copy the file you find in there, this is called your *keystore* file and it contains the private key to your account.

Now on your other device (if you're using mist) click on `Accounts --» Import wallet file` and drag and drop the file you copied from your mac here. You will then be able to access your account on the new device.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, my wallet was mist (downloaded from ethereum.org).  I did what you suggested above, and the file seemed to transfer to the new device (a PC this time).  The blockchain was never fully downloaded on the mac, does that matter?  Like the mac, the PC was taking forever to download the blockchain, and it wasn't clear that I was even connected.  I downloaded Parity, thinking that would speed things up, but wasn't sure how to use it.  So much jargon I don't understand.

Comment: No problem :) Don't worry about the blockchain not being fully downloaded on your mac, it won't affect your account in any way. So did you manage to access your account on the PC in the end or is it still syncing? Parity is a different wallet that by default syncs the blockchain much faster by only downloading a very limited history, you can import your account there if you want but yeah, it's a whole different interface to learn :P With the next major version of Ethereum (Metropolis) things should get a lot easier to use.